# PHP equivalent to [&, epsilon] C++ "Capturing" variables in lambda?

Tags: php, lambda

Is there a way I can pass any variable currently in scope by reference to a lambda function without listing them all in the `use(...)` statement?

Something like

```
$foo = 12;
$bar = 'hello';

$run = function() use (&) {
    $foo = 13;
    $bar = 'bye';
}

// execute $run function
```

Resulting in `$foo` equal to `13` and `$bar` equal to `'bye'`.

Comment: In short: no, there is no shorthand.

Comment: A named function does not allow the `use` keyword.

Comment: @Sylwester sorry for this, I edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*TL;DR The short answer is no. You need to name the variables*

You don't need closure variables for this. It's not even valid to use `use` with named functions since it won't have a nested lexical scope. Use the [`global`](https://www.php.net/language.variables.scope) keyword to make the variables "dynamic". You have to name all the variables that are special.

```php
$foo = 12;
$bar = 'hello';

function run() {
    global $foo,$bar;
    $foo = 13;
    $bar = 'bye';
}

run();
print "$foo, $bar\n"; // prints "13, bye"
```

For a lexical anonymous functions you need to name all variables with the [`use`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) keyword and use `&` to get it referenced:

```php
$foo = 12;
$bar = 'hello';

$run = function () use (&$foo,&$bar) {
    $foo = 13;
    $bar = 'bye';
};
call_user_func($run); 
print "$foo, $bar\n"; // prints "13, bye"
```

Comment: The "current" scope and the *global* scope are not necessarily the same. Hopefully they *usually aren't.*

Comment: @deceze Thats not true. You see it clearly in the example that the named function does not have other lexical `$foo` or `$bar`. If it would have been an anonymous function the matter would have been different.

Comment: 1) The example is clearly pseudo code, as it's invalid. 2) The OP explicitly talks about *lambda* (anonymous) functions and *"current"* scope. Your answer is useful only for a tiny subset of use cases, which you would at least need to clarify.

Comment: Indeed, I was talking about lambda, forgive me for the "named function", I just edit the code sample.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `get_defined_vars()` along with `extract()`:

```
$foo = 12;
$bar = 'hello';

$vars = get_defined_vars();

foreach (array_keys($vars) as $var) {
    $vars[$var] = &$$var; // keep refs of all variables from current scope
}

$run = function() use($vars) {
    extract($vars, EXTR_REFS);
    $foo = 13;
    $bar = 'bye';
};

// execute $run function
$run();
print $foo; // prints 13
print $bar; // prints bye
```